# Toolbar in Keyboard top with done Button and textfield Navigation

Tags: swift, ios9

I've seen that in many apps but I can't find an useful tutorial online.
How can I realize something like that in Swift?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, So you need to add a `UITextField` to your NavigationBar. Here's the code that should help you :

```
var textField=UITextField()
//Configure the size and other properties..
self.navigationItem.titleView = textField
```

And for the button on the right, you should do this :

```
var button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "FOO", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "FOO")
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
```

That's all done there, but I strongly think that you shouldn't add a login form to your navigation bar, it's very impractical.

Comment: Well, but I'd like to use this in a login form.